# consuming all the object type messages from a queue

Tags: spring-integration

I have the below configuration which will connect to a particular queue on jms and will consume message from that queue and will write to a file

now the issue is that on the queue the message is of type object type or of  string type also and i want to consume object type message only

so for example below is the body of the message which is of object type so the message headers value is

```
ObjectMessage={ Header={ JMSMessageID={ID:LON_TEST_GAWE_4533.351656B16070206DEBAE:1936} JMSDestination={Queue[erty.retry.object]} JMSReplyTo={null} JMSDeliveryMode={PERSISTENT} JMSRedelivered={false} JMSCorrelationID={null} JMSType={null} JMSTimestamp={Fri Feb 26 11:52:53 IST 2016} JMSExpiration={0} JMSPriority={4} } Properties={ } Object={?} }
```

as you have notice above that for object message the initials text in the message headers begains with `ObjectMessage={ Header={ JMSMessageID={ID:LON`

so please advise how can i consume all object type message is there any way by which i can them and store them in a file

bwlow is my configuration rite now..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
    xmlns:file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"

    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd    
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <int:poller id="poller" default="true">
        <int:interval-trigger interval="200" />
    </int:poller>



    <int:channel id="input">
        <int:queue capacity="10" />
    </int:channel>

    <bean id="tibcoEMSJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory
                </prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://wert2.fm.absgrp.net:3453</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">aert</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">aert</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tibcoEMSConnFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="tibcoEMSJndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>GenericConnectionFactory</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tibcosendJMSTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <ref bean="tibcoEMSConnFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="defaultDestinationName">
            <value>erty.retry.object</value>
        </property>
        <property name="pubSubDomain">
            <value>false</value>
        </property>
        <property name="receiveTimeout">
            <value>120000</value>
        </property>
    </bean>




<!--    <jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="input" 
        destination-name="erty.retry.object" connection-factory="tibcoEMSConnFactory" /> -->


<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn" concurrent-consumers="10"
        destination-name="erty.retry.object"  connection-factory="tibcoEMSConnFactory" extract-payload="false"
        channel="jmsInChannel" />

    <int:channel id="jmsInChannel" />



 <file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesout"  channel="jmsInChannel" directory="C:\\dfgal"
 filename-generator="generatorr" />

<bean id="generatorr" class="com.rbs.tibco.TimestampTextGenerator">
    </bean>




    <int:payload-type-router input-channel="jmsInChannel"></int:payload-type-router>

<bean id="generatorr" class="com.rbs.tibco.TimestampTextGenerator">
    </bean>




</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems for me I have seen similar question here on SO. I don't want to find it to be sure that was from you and there was some answer.

Please, be sure that you use the search before asking unclear questions.

First of all your solution looks weird from the architecture perspective.

Even if we can do something like that, the JMS isn't so flexible to be partitioned like it is possible with Kafka.

I mean that it isn't so convenient for the consumer to read different message types from the same queue. The main problem that consumers reads ALL messages from the queue. I'm not sure that just filter those text messages and drop them is a good solution for your system.

Anyway you can use `extract-payload = "false"` on the `<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>` meaning that the whole JMS `Message` will be as Spring Integration Message `payload`. After that you can use `<payload-type-router>` and distinguish an `ObjectMessage` from `TextMessage` and send them to the different channel: the first one to store in the file, another to something else.

Hope I am clear.

Comment: Thanks you very much yeah the approach is crystal clear , please advise how i will distinguish the object message from text message Request you to please show a code bit of payload type router performing this based on my above message example , That will be great to understand and grasp, Thanks in advance

Comment: can i do something like this <int:payload-type-router input-channel="jmsInChannel">
    <int:mapping type="java.lang.Object" channel="objetChannel" />
    <int:mapping type="java.lang.String" channel="StringChannel" />
</int:payload-type-router>

Comment: You go right way with the concept, but I pointed you that you should distinguish with the `javax.jms.ObjectMessage` and `javax.jms.TextMessage`. That's how that `extract-payload = "false"` will help you to track the whole JMS message.

Comment: Thanks one again yeah very much correct I will add these also please advise as I am putting the object message in a separate channel named object channel can I add transformer in between to convert java. Jms.textmessgae to string through object to string transformer so that at last u will be storing string message in objectchannel

Comment: Yes, you definitely should use some transformer to convert a JMS Message to something appropriate for you. Although the out-of-the-box `ObjectToStringTransformer` won't help you. Consider to utilize the logic from the `org.springframework.jms.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter` on the matter. Exactly this one is used in the `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>` by default and with the `extract-payload = "true"`.

Comment: Thanks once again but let's say my objective was to distinguish the message type which I am able to achieve through payload type router and storing the different message type on different channel's,  and then all the object message in a text file which I can achieve rite now without transfer also.

Comment: Not sure then what is the question. That may be really fully different topic to discuss in the new SO thread. If I answered to your original question, let's consider to accept it and go ahead with something new!

Comment: Sure Thanks a lot for your advise really appreciate.