# messages not getting consumed depending whether the message is of type text or string

Tags: spring-integration

Below i have the program to send a message and consume a message from queue , rite now i have commented out the sending part and only want to consume the messages from queue , the message can be type of string or object message for which i have configure router.

Now there are text message in the queue which my below program is not consuming please advise how to overcome from this below is my configuration , as you can see i have commented out the sender part so the only reading part from the queue is the active one

and also when rite now i have observe that messages are getting consumed but files are not being generated so this means that there is some error after payload router i have configured

```
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd    
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <int:poller id="poller" default="true">
        <int:interval-trigger interval="200" />
    </int:poller>



    <int:channel id="input">
        <int:queue capacity="10" />
    </int:channel>

    <bean id="tibcoEMSJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory
                </prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://lsdrtems2.fm.crdgrp.net:7333</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">acfgtir</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">acfgtir</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tibcoEMSConnFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="tibcoEMSJndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>GenericConnectionFactory</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tibcosendJMSTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <ref bean="tibcoEMSConnFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="defaultDestinationName">
            <value>acfgtirrtyation.ioa.swretift_publish_poc1</value>
        </property>
        <property name="pubSubDomain">
            <value>false</value>
        </property>
        <property name="receiveTimeout">
            <value>120000</value>
        </property>
    </bean>




    <!-- <jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="input" 
        destination-name="acfgtirrtyation.ioa.swretift_publish_poc1" connection-factory="tibcoEMSConnFactory" /> -->

<int:channel id="objetChannel"></int:channel>
<int:channel id="StringChannel"></int:channel>
<int:channel id="jmsInChannel" />



<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn" concurrent-consumers="10"
        destination-name="acfgtirrtyation.ioa.swretift_publish_poc1"  connection-factory="tibcoEMSConnFactory" extract-payload="false"
        channel="jmsInChannel" />

    <int:payload-type-router input-channel="jmsInChannel">
    <int:mapping type="javax.jms.ObjectMessage" channel="objetChannel" />
     <int:mapping type="javax.jms.TextMessage" channel="StringChannel" />
    </int:payload-type-router>



 <file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesoutOject"  channel="objetChannel" directory="C:\\abcsaral"
 filename-generator="generatorr" />



 <file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesoutString"  channel="StringChannel" directory="C:\\abcsaral"
 filename-generator="generatorr" />

<bean id="generatorr" class="com.abs.tibco.TimestampTextGenerator">
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Folks please advise for this any early help would be much appreciated

below is the timestamp generator class as shown below

```
public class TimestampTextGenerator implements FileNameGenerator {



    @Override
    public String generateFileName(Message<?> arg0) {
        return new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss.SSS")
        .format(new java.util.Date()) + ".txt";
    }

}
```

Folks please advise as I am completely stuck up on this..!

Answer (score 0):

Remove this attribute `extract-payload="false"` in your `message-driven-channel-adapter`. It changes expected payload type and your `payload-type-router` doesn't work.

Also look this [20.1. Inbound Channel Adapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jms.html#jms-inbound-channel-adapter) manual chapter.

Comment: Thanks a lot but the logic to implement it there was to disitinguis that javax.text .message and javax.object.message , will that scenario will work in that case

Comment: @sss I see... what are real messages payload type you use? I see `String` and what is the real type of you `Objects`? Why do you prefer not use raw Java types but `javax.jms.*` types?

Comment: @Andy actually my task is to consume the messages from the queue and the queue is basically a tibco queue to which i connect and now there are some queues which will contain object message and there are some queues which will contain text messages , so i want to separate text messages into separate channel and object messages into separate channel and ultimately storing every message in afile

Comment: @AndriyKryvtsun, please, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to understand what's wrong with your application is to take a look into logs. I should admit that sometimes Java is more smarter than me :-).

See Gary Russel's answer for you on the matter: [Enabling logging in spring integration utiliy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679340/enabling-logging-in-spring-integration-utiliy)

Please, try to follow with all our answers to you around this topic.

I suggested you to use `extract-payload="false"` to get the whole `javax.jms.ObjectMessage` or `javax.jms.TextMessage` as a `payload` independently of the conversion result, when the `javax.jms.ObjectMessage` maybe converted to the `java.lang.String` as well. Although, right, in most case the routing based just only on the `java.lang.String` and all others should work, too.

Now about the  `<file:outbound-channel-adapter>` problem. If you take a into logs you should see something like:

```
else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "unsupported Message payload type [" + payload.getClass().getName() + "]");
}
```

M-m-m, yeah, I mean the result of this Exception in logs. Just because your `payload` is `javax.jms.Message`, but to write into file you should supply `File`, `InputStream`, `byte[]` or `String`.

So, as I said in comments to my answer ([consuming all the object type messages from a queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650969/consuming-all-the-object-type-messages-from-a-queue)) to your similar question, you should convert the message after routing into some appropriate type for  `<file:outbound-channel-adapter>`.