# Enabling logging in spring integration utility

Tags: spring-integration

Below I have the program to send a message and consume a message from queue, right now I have commented out the sending part and only want to consume the messages from queue

Now I want to enable logging in the below program such that a log file is generated in my c: drive and inside that log file it should indicate that what message it is consuming at what time stamp please advise how to configure logging in the below configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
    xmlns:file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd    
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <int:poller id="poller" default="true">
        <int:interval-trigger interval="200" />
    </int:poller>



    <int:channel id="input">
        <int:queue capacity="10" />
    </int:channel>

    <bean id="tibcoEMSJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory
                </prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://lsdrtems2.fm.crdgrp.net:7333</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">acfgtir</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">acfgtir</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tibcoEMSConnFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="tibcoEMSJndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>GenericConnectionFactory</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tibcosendJMSTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <ref bean="tibcoEMSConnFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="defaultDestinationName">
            <value>acfgtirrtyation.ioa.swretift_publish_poc1</value>
        </property>
        <property name="pubSubDomain">
            <value>false</value>
        </property>
        <property name="receiveTimeout">
            <value>120000</value>
        </property>
    </bean>




    <!-- <jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="input" 
        destination-name="acfgtirrtyation.ioa.swretift_publish_poc1" connection-factory="tibcoEMSConnFactory" /> -->

<int:channel id="objetChannel"></int:channel>
<int:channel id="StringChannel"></int:channel>
<int:channel id="jmsInChannel" />



<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn" concurrent-consumers="10"
        destination-name="acfgtirrtyation.ioa.swretift_publish_poc1"  connection-factory="tibcoEMSConnFactory" extract-payload="false"
        channel="jmsInChannel" />

    <int:payload-type-router input-channel="jmsInChannel">
    <int:mapping type="javax.jms.ObjectMessage" channel="objetChannel" />
     <int:mapping type="javax.jms.TextMessage" channel="StringChannel" />
    </int:payload-type-router>



 <file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesoutOject"  channel="objetChannel" directory="C:\\abcsaral"
 filename-generator="generatorr" />



 <file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesoutString"  channel="StringChannel" directory="C:\\abcsaral"
 filename-generator="generatorr" />

<bean id="generatorr" class="com.abs.tibco.TimestampTextGenerator">
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Answer (score 7):

Add log4j (or logback, or any java logging system supported by commons-logging) to your classpath and configure it to log a DEBUG level for category `org.springframework.integration`.

Or you can add a [wire tap](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-wiretap) to the channel and route it to a Logging channel adapter

> ```
> <int:channel id="in">
>     <int:interceptors>
>         <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
>     </int:interceptors>
> </int:channel>
>
> <int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" level="DEBUG"/>
> ```

Comment: IThanks I am thinking to introduce wire tap just to check what is happening inside the channel

Comment: Yes; you can do that too - I edited the answer at the same time you posted this comment.

Comment: Thanks Gary can you please explain a bit about logging channel adapter also it will be great if you can please add it to any one of the channel above so that I can grasp.

Comment: See the documentation I pointed you to; it's pretty simple; [this sample app](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/amqp/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/spring-integration-context.xml#L42) has one.

Comment: Can I ask, the steps in detail? I have a chain with http-outbound-gateway. I used the thename in input-channel for log channel. <int:channel id="statusInChannel"><int:interceptors><int:wire-tap channel="loggingChannel" /></int:interceptors></int:channel>. added logging channel adapter as in answer above. But I see a message - Adding {bridge:null} as a subscriber to the 'dest-channel' channel. Channel 'application.dest-channel' has 2 subscriber(s). I dont understand - "configure it to log a DEBUG level for category org.springframework.integration"

Comment: Don't put code in comments; it's unreadable; and don't ask questions in comments on  4 year old answers. Ask a new question showing all components that reference `dest-channel`.