# How to consume AWS SQS message with more than just String in header?

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have a Spring Integration project configured to consume messages from a AWS SQS and when a message with just `String` headers and a simple body is produced, the processor consumes it quickly.

But when I try to consume a message that have, let's suppose, a Binary.xml inside the header attributes, the message just got *on the flight* but it's never consumed. What's the matter with Spring Integration? Can someone help me?

I've try to use a *wire tap* to see depth logs ([Enabling logging in spring integration utiliy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679340/enabling-logging-in-spring-integration-utiliy)) but nothing was shown.

```
<int:channel id="in">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" level="TRACE"/>
```

My *connectionFactory* bean:

```
<bean id="basicAWSCredential" class="com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials"
          primary="true">
    <constructor-arg value="${awsAccessKey}"/>
    <constructor-arg value="${awsSecretKey}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="AWSCredentialProvider" class="com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider"
      primary="true">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="basicAWSCredential"></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="AWSClientBuilder" class="com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClientBuilder"
      factory-method="standard" primary="true">
    <property name="region" value="${awsRegion}"/>
    <property name="credentials" ref="AWSCredentialProvider"/>
</bean>

<bean id="SQSProviderConfiguration" class="com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.ProviderConfiguration">
    <property name="numberOfMessagesToPrefetch" value="20"/>
</bean>

<bean id="connectionFactory" class="com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.SQSConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="SQSProviderConfiguration"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="AWSClientBuilder"/>
</bean>
```

My consumer bean:

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
    channel="RouteByFileCompressionChannel" connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    destination-name="MyQueueName" concurrent-consumers="10"
    acknowledge="client" max-concurrent-consumers="20" id="SqsInboundAdapter" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"a Binary.xml inside the header attributes"*? That is just a string like any other, is it not? Maybe it is too large? Can you manually poll the message from SQS, does that work, does a client with spring integration receive the message?

Comment: OMG man, someone just designed the application to produce a message with a custom header, I can't believe this guys. I'm really in shame. Thanks a lot for your comment, you'd save my night, if you want to answer clarifying the problem you've already found, I would be ok to accept the answer, Thanks again.

Comment: I don't even know *what* I solved but I'm happy you are happy :D

Comment: Some naughty dev inserted a custom type (called Binary.xml) for a header and the Spring Integration consumers just stopped working.

Comment: I think the issue is somewhere before Spring Integration yet. You can turn on `DEBUG` logging level for the `org.springframework.integration` to be sure what's going on at the JMS level. Also I think you can do the same for the `com.amazon.sqs` category to trace how AWS Service poll the message from the SQS before publishing it to the Spring Integration listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was a custom type in one of the headers.

The `Binary.xml` custom type couldn't be parsed by the Spring Integration JMS Adapter, so nothing happen when I produce a message with this type. I don't know who produced such header but now I fixed all the producers along the application.

Thanks a lot for those who helped me here.